# Import module from child folder instead of same directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-module

So I have the following file structure (win10)

```
project/
        mycode.py
        lib/
           bunch of python modules
           paramiko/
                    all of paramiko's files
```

Here, all the modules are in a child folder, and when I say
`import paramiko` in mycode.py, it can't find paramiko. However, when I move them all out of the lib directory, it works fine.

Working solution:

```
project/
        mycode.py
        bunch of python modules
        paramiko/
                 all of paramiko's files
```

But it's ugly, and I'd rather have all of them in a lib directory. How do I access modules in a child directory?

Edit: Okay, figured it out. I used os. to add to the path:

```
projectPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(projectPath+"\\lib")
```

which I had tried before, except this time, **i moved the import paramiko to after the edits made to the path**. God I feel stupid sometimes

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without adding it to the path:

```
from lib import paramiko
```

OR

```
import lib.paramiko
```

As long as you have the directory structure like this

```
project/
        mycode.py
        lib/
           bunch of python modules
           paramiko/
                    all of paramiko's files
```

Comment: The first results in :```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\skylight\skylight.py", line 18, in <module>
    from lib import paramiko
  File "E:\skylight\lib\paramiko\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from paramiko._version import __version__, __version_info__
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paramiko'```

And the second in the same.

Comment: If you're executing `import lib.paramiko` in `mycode.py` it should work, mine is working with similar structure.